# MAC APP development WKWebView just fail to load page. can't figure out why

Tags: swift, macos

I have a local HTML in my project, which is a very simple one, and I just can't show it in my mac app; don't know why.

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setWkWebView()
    loadHtml()
}

func setWkWebView(){
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    let config = webView.configuration
    let preference = WKPreferences()
    preference.javaEnabled = true
    let wkUserController = WKUserContentController()
    wkUserController.add(self, name: "jsToSwift")
    config.preferences = preference
    config.userContentController = wkUserController
}
func loadHtml(){
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test.html", ofType: nil)
    let htmlString:String?
    do {
        htmlString = try String.init(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: .utf8)
    } catch {
        htmlString = nil
    }
    let urlString = "https://www.bilibili.com"
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!))
    // webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString!, baseURL: URL(string: path!))
}

func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    print(message)
    if (message.name == "jsToSwift"){
        print("jsToSwift success")
        let buttonIndicat = NSButton(frame: NSRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 70, height: 70))
        buttonIndicat.title = "jsToSwift"
        webView.addSubview(buttonIndicat)
    }
}
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: the same code works fine in my iOS app, why this is failing in mac ???

Answer (score 0):

One possibility might be because MacOS apps are (in recent OS/Xcode versions) sandboxed by default.  You'll probably need to select "outgoing connections (Client)" in order to make WWW and (required for WWW to work) DNS requests.  There are also restrictions on local file access.

Click below to see a picture of the Xcode entitlement section, under "capabilities".

[xcode entitlement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20gPI.png)